# People see my connections on LinkedIn, despite the setting set to "only me"

Tags: privacy, linkedin

Why can people, who are among my connections, see all my connections (even if they're not common to both), even though on privacy settings I selected "only me" to see the connections? Another buddy, one from my connections, also has this setting, and I cannot see her connections (can't click the number of connections).